# disable lid sleep in mojave

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave

I used to use InsomniaX but it doesn't work for me right now.

I want to stop my MacBook from sleeping when I close the lid.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of [KeepingYouAwake](https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake). It works pretty well in macOS Mojave. It's a GUI based wrapper around Apple's `caffeniate` command line utility. All current versions of macOS ship with `caffeniate` tool built-in. So, it should be safe to use.

**Courtesy:** https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake/#how-does-it-work

For installation:

- You can download latest version from [here](https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake/releases), or
- Install it using Homebrew by running: `brew cask install keepingyouawake`

**Reference:** https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake/#installation

Comment: KeepingYouAwake is great app to prevent your Mac from sleeping. However, it doesn't prevent sleep while the lid of a MacBook is closed.